# RhysW's Tag Reviews - Suggested Course of action

Tags: discussion, tags

So I have recently been having a batter at the tags to see if we can remove any we don't need. Define any that are undefined and re-tag those we think are redundant.

As suggested by Monica Cellio I will instead post an answer for each tag as well as what I think should be done with it, agreement / disagreement is then as simple as a up or down vote.

Feel free to disagree and explain why if you do so. I can't do the deletions myself so will rely on community agreement to determine what we should do with each of these tags.

Comment: cliches and humor look like [meta-tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/meta-tags/info "what's this") to me. Meta tags are an "officially certified" target for deletion

Comment: Can we add ettiquette to this list... ettiquette is not a workplace topic

Comment: Tags with fewer than 2 uses eventually fade away on their own; there's no explicit "remove" step.  I *believe* that this now does not apply to tags that have wikis, though, so if you want to kill a tag with a wiki, you need to kill the wiki too.

Comment: Suggestion: if the question were just "which tags should we clean up?" and then separate answers covered individual tags or groups of related tags, then voting would indicate community support.  Otherwise you're going to have to tease it out from comments or possibly competing mega-answers.

Comment: @Chad [tag:etiquette] has 143 questions, and is likely to be a controversial deletion target.  I suggest you start a new question if you want to involve controversial targets, as RhysW's list is mostly uncontroversial.

Comment: @NickC - Only a very few are even arguably ettiquette questions though most of them are professionalism many of them are just about other people being asshats  I started removing them and was chastized

Comment: @Chad the point is this list is about obvious cleanup.  If you don't see the difference then I'm not sure what else to say about it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio well suggested, this is now how its done

Comment: @NickC i took the liberty of creating a question like that myself this morning if its the sort of thing you wouldnt mind giving a glance

Answer (score 4):

**[humor](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor)** - This tag isn't even on any questions nor do I see it having a use as it is essentially a meta tag.

I suggest total removal of this tag.

**Update: Removed from all questions, awaiting tag to fade away**

Answer (score 4):

**[business](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business)** and **[company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/company)** - These are both very ambiguous in their use age, there doesn't seem to be any predefined pattern to how these are used.

**If anything I would say these tags are redundant and should be burninated**.

Answer (score 3):

**[Cliches](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cliches)** - This was used on only one question which has been downvoted and closed. The tag serves no purpose.

I suggest removal from the question followed by removal of the tag itself.

**Update: The question with this tag is now deleted; tag will fade away if not used again**

Answer (score 3):

**[library](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/library)** - I'm unsure if this tag serves any purpose. Anywhere I can see it being used could be replaced by education or training

Suggested deletion of this tag.

**Update: Added deletion votes to the question with this tag (question is closed and negative, awaiting question to be deleted for the tag to fade away**

Answer (score 3):

**[alertness](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alertness)** - A meta-tag describing the state of the person, not describing the problem.

I suggest deletion of this tag

**Update: Removed from all questions, awaiting tag to fade away**

Answer (score 3):

**[conversation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversation)** - Used once on a now closed question. Doesn't seem to serve any purpose that communication would not.

Suggested removal

**Update: Added deletion votes to the question with this tag (question is closed and negative, awaiting question to be deleted for the tag to fade away**

Answer (score 2):

**[batna](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batna)** - As jmac correctly pointed out to me this doesn't infact refer to a small town in algeria it is infact an acronym for

> Best alternative to a negotiated agreement

In either case we already have negotiation that can be used for this tag. I removed it from the one question it was on and I suggest deletion / removal of this tag.

**Update: Removed from all questions, awaiting tag to fade away**

Answer (score 2):

**[server](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/server)** - This is being used as a term relating to a specific piece of equipment, unless we are also going to make tags for holepuncher, stapler and pens I suggest we remove this tag.

**Update: Removed from all questions, awaiting tag to fade away**

Comment: I agree with killing that one use of this tag.  The tag name itself made me wonder: is there a tag for IT stuff in general, covering things like web filters, email (non-)privacy, use of corporate machines for personal use, etc?  Do we need something like that?  (Asking in a comment because I'm really not fluent in all our tags, so I don't know if a new meta question even makes sense.)

Comment: There is one for email, but the specific equipment like a server, and a stapler and a drawer isnt really needed, its all meta-tags describing the stuff in the problem, not the problem itself. Whereas email is a tool for communication and thus presents many (industry nonspecific) questions along that front.

Comment: Yeah, email in the sense of its *content* is different from what I meant.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**[promises](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/promises)** - This tag is used only once to describe the situation more than the problem.

Suggested deletion of this tag.

Answer (score 1):

**[hardware](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware)** - A meta-tag describing the equipment (like server).

Suggested removal of this tag

Comment: See [this comment](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/rhysws-tag-reviews-suggested-course-of-action#comment3035_2015).

Answer (score 1):

**[job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job)** - This tag seems redundant because every question here will relate to a job in some way therefore **I suggest a burnination of this tag**

Answer (score 1):

**[injury-prevention](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/injury-prevention)** - This is used in one place, it's not really any different from the health tag (health is defined as: Questions relating to ones physical or mental well-being)

Comment: This might make a good synonym (for health) rather than outright removal.

Comment: Seems like this could be part of [tag:safety]? Though that tag doesn't exist..

Comment: @enderland i was thinking along the same lines, we have a health tag, seems like a safety tag would be good to go along with it

Comment: Kill injury-prevention and define safety as a synonym for health?  That works.

Answer (score 1):

**[credentials](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/credentials)** - This is used on one question only, and even there it could be interchangeable with certification.

Suggested deletion of this tag.

Answer (score 0):

**[work-time](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-time)** - There is no real pattern to how people are using this tag. The closest i can find might be to do with it being during working hours, but as this is the workplace then nearly every question is going to be during work hours so this tag servers no purpose.

Suggested deletion of this tag.

Comment: these seem to be about work schedules - could be over time, but more about start and stop times, communication after hours

Comment: @mhoran_psprep so perhaps a redefinition of the tag would be more beneficial?

Answer (score 0):

**[location](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/location)** Less than 10 questions mostly for asking about relocation or about two offices that are in different places, could probably be removed and replaced by other relevant tags as applicable

Comment: questions about relocation should be tagged... [tag:relocation]

Answer (score -1):

**[corporate-structure](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corporate-structure)** - this is on one down voted and closed question and doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

Suggested deletion of this tag

Comment: This could be part of a lot of good, meaningful questions in my opinion.

Comment: @enderland thats a good point, i was sort of torn about this one but having not seen any questions currently tagged with it i was unsure

Comment: @enderland and when someone asks one it can come back, no?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I think I am optimistic someone will bring some questions which are good, hard, and indepth questions using a tag of [tag:corporate-structure] :)