# Another tag discussion!

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I have done some research into tag cleanup and am looking for community feedback.

Just like when [RhysW did the same thing](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2005/rhysws-tag-reviews-suggested-course-of-action), I will post one answer for each recommendation, feel free to add your own.

ps. I don't actually have enough rep to make synonyms or insta-edit, etc. so it probably won't be me making these changes (as much as I would love to help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have completed the following:

- [systemsadmin](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemsadmin) has been removed from three questions and [systemsengineering](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemsengineering) as well from one of them (discussed [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2796/7945))
- Made [usa](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa) a synonym of [united-states](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) (thanks Monica! discussed [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2787/7945))
- [recommendation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) has been changed to [recommendation-letter](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation-letter) on all 14 questions (discussed [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2794/7945))
- [firing](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firing) has been changed to [termination](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/termination) and a synonym has been created (discussed [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2785/7945))
- [industry-conference](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industry-conference) has been changed and made a synonym of [conferences](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conferences) (as discussed [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2788/7945))

Answer (score 6):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Synonym** [united-states](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) and [usa](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa)

Yes.

- united-states has 92 questions and a proper tag wiki
- usa has 6 questions and its wiki says "*United States of America*".

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: This one seems uncontroversial, and uk->united-kingdom already exists (so there's a precedent).  I've implemented this.

Answer (score 6):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Burninate** [systemadmin](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systemadmin)

I think the tag is too technical/specific and is unlikely to be of any help.

Answer (score 5):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Retag** [hiring](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiring) to  [hiring-process](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiring-process)

As per Monica Cellio's suggestion.

- hiring-process has 280 questions and a tag wiki
- hiring has 2

Comment: I'd say just retag the two hiring questions.  Once the tag is deleted for non-use, anybody typing "hiring" will be offered "hiring-process".  I suspect the "hiring" tag was a typo.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I just did that: [retagged 1](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/31164/revisions), [retagged 2](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/30777/revisions)

Comment: Thank you @gnat.

Answer (score 5):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Synonym** [termination](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/termination) and [firing](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firing)

I think this one is pretty clear

- termination has 27 questions and a tag wiki (which says "*also known as being fired*")
- firing has 10 questions and no wiki.

Comment: well "fired" is a special case of termination for example for a Q about redundancy or layoffs a "fired" tag would be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks RhysW!

**Burninate** [company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/company) and [business](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business)

I fail to see how these tag can add any value to a question:

- there are 10 questions which use company, no tag wiki.
- there are 15 questions which use business, no tag wiki.
- there one question which only uses it as a tag and it has been closed
- I don't think anyone can be an expert in [company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/company) or [business](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business)
- *pretty much every question on the site is about a company/business or has a company/business involved*
- It has already [been recommended to be burninated](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2021/19839) a year ago

Answer (score 5):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks RhysW!

**Burninate** [white-collar](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/white-collar)

I don't think it is very helpful and is minimally used.

- There are only 2 questions using the tag and they both also use the white-collar tag (and they were both closed)
- There is no tag wiki.
- *I can totally see someone asking about white-collar crime with this tag (and not in a good way...)*

Answer (score 5):

**Retag** [tech-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tech-industry) and [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry)

I'm studying computer engineering, I know that the tech industry isn't just software, but the questions using this tag don't totally agree.

- software-industry has 454 questions and a proper tag wiki
- tech-industry has <strike>21 17 18</strike> 14 questions and no wiki

However this is not the whole story, as I mentioned, tech does not solely mean software. Of the 14 questions:

- <strike>15 11 6</strike> 5 should be tagged software-industry (the questions are all closed)
- 8 need either tag (its not clear in the question which is more applicable) (6 of which are closed)
- 1 should have the tag

What I am seeing is that the tag is being used improperly, I think that a retagging should do the trick, but it might just get misused again. Thoughts?

Comment: I propose that we burninate the 'tech-industry' tag.

Comment: For now Ian, if you can retag the ones that don't merit the tag, it will make cleanup easier later.

Comment: I started retagging but I only did 4 today, I will do another 4 each day (not to overwhelm the review queue/front page). What should be done about retagging the closed questions?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I retagged it because a) they said they were a software dev, b) they said: "...or are companies who's primary product is not software" indicating their concern that they might not be good for software dev and c) the questions indicates that they are looking for a technical job (likely in software) but beyond that it is unimportant to the question. By retagging the post to a more popular tag I am hoping to make it easier to find (its obvious to anyone who looks that there is the software-industry tag, but you have to go through pages to find tech-industry).

Comment: Do we really need a software industry tag in the first place? Is the industry providing critical information required to answer, or help categorize those questions?

Comment: @jmac I think we do, but the discussion probably deserves its own meta post.

Answer (score 5):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Different tag?** [recommendation](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendation)

The tag wiki is pretty clear, the tag is for letters of recommendation, but at first glance I might think that it is for making a recommendation to my colleagues or company (we should use jquery!). **Can rename it to [recommendation-letter] or something?**

Answer (score 3):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Retag** [industry-conference](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industry-conference) to [conference](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conference)

I don't feel that adding industry to conference adds anything new to it and is less easy to guess when adding tags...

- There are 5 questions for industry-conference with no wiki
- There is 1 questions for conference but there is a tag wiki.

I don't think we need both tags but please share your thoughts on this one.

Answer (score 2):

**Umm...** [consultants](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consultants) and [consulting](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consulting)

These tags could be different with consulting being used for questions where the asker is the consultant and the consultants tag being used for hiring or handling consultants. However I am seeing that the consulting tag is being used in the way mentioned earlier, but the consultant tag is being used for both.

As it stands I don't think that having both tags is useful, with a retagging and a wiki on each one they could be. What course of action is best?

Answer (score 2):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thanks RhysW!

**Burninate** [reinterview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reinterview)

I think this tag it too localized to be helpful in the future.

- There are only 2 questions using the tag and they both also use the interviewing tag
- The difference between reinterviewing and interviewing can easily be specified in the title
- I think it would be difficult to ask another question with this tag without it being a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

**Synonym or retag** [professionalism](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professionalism) and [unprofessional-behaviour](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unprofessional-behaviour)

Professionalism includes unprofessional-behaviour.

- Professionalism has a lot of questions
- unprofessional-behaviour has 12, no wiki.

While I could argue that unprofessional-behaviour might be helpful, I think there are too many questions tagged with professionalism which apply to unprofessional-behaviour to make the tags worth staying separate.

Answer (score 0):

**Synonym** (or retag and burninate) [software-industry](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry) and [developer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developer)

Developer is just a software-developer, which I think fits in the software-industry tag.

- developer has 18 questions and no tag wiki
- software-industry has 454 questions and a tag wiki.

I don't see any questions in the developer tag which are not about software development.

Comment: This has become its own question: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2828/

Answer (score -2):

> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

**Burninate** [fresher](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fresher)

<strike>*I had no idea what a fresher was until I saw the tag wiki*</strike>

Comment: Maybe we could make this a synonym of [first-job](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-job) which seems to be more widely used (10 questions) than fresher's 2. On the other hand, the term "fresher" itself shows up in 18 questions, they are just not tagged appropriately

Comment: I thought about it, but just because it's you're fresh out of college doesn't mean its your first job...

Comment: This is a very common phrase outside the western world.

Comment: @enderland I hadn't thought of that. I should have been more clear on my suggestion. I feel (partially because it is almost unused and partially because it seems like an obscure term) that it is unlikely to be used when people are just guessing what tags apply to their question. But I guess if that was the only reason to burninate a tag then there would be a lot less tags...