# Should the drugtest tag be killed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

So, there is a question posed recently concerning [how an applicant may have messed up faking a drug test](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54075/worried-that-drug-test-didnt-go-well). The only other question under the [drugtest](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drugtest) tag is closed as off topic. Since there is very little advise we can give for positive drug test results, and the question will probably be very subjective "Do you think I'll get hired if my employer requires a drug test and I have THC in my system", I'm wondering if maybe this tag should be killed. I'm not sure how it would have got in the tag pool, since neither of the two questioners have more than 20 rep's.

Comment: The tag was suggested in [an edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/48181/2). Though he doesn't have the required 1500 rep for a mature site, I'm assuming this edit dates back to the public beta where [only 150 rep is required to create a tag.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/260382)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

Tags with no questions are already [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/260382). This tag has two questions which are currently closed. While I can imagine questions that would be on-topic here that could use it, such a tag can just be recreated then if there is a need for it.

It might be worth launching another [tag cleanup](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/another-tag-discussion) round to avoid creating new discussions for each tag but I'll agree that this one can go.

Answer (score 2):

I just edited it out of the one remaining question.

It will shortly be deleted automatically.